# Como puedo guardar fecha en sqlServer en c# usando un DataTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

estoy intentando guardar la fecha en sqlserver desde un DataTimerPicker, uso `c#`, pero el error que me arroja es: no se puede convertir el tipo varchar en fecha/hora mi codigo es:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaAlta", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtmFechaAlta.Value;
```

Estoy usando paramatros y solo quiero guardar la fecha en el campo de mi tabla de la base de
datos, que se encuentra Tipo Date

No se cual podría ser el error, si me pueden ayudar

Comment: Parece que SQL Server no entiende el formato de hora que le estás enviando. Qué valor lleva `dtmFechaAlta.Value`? Utiliza SQLProfiler para capturar la consulta a la base de datos y también podrás ver qué valor lleva.

Comment: Hola @Arriel, uso SqlServer 2016 Express

Comment: dtmFechaAlta.Value? A que te refieres exactamente? me explicas por favor gracias

Comment: @lavasoftNelson, podrias marcar la respuesta como aceptada y darle un voto si lo deseas, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error puede darte quizá porque estás tratando de introducir un **valor fecha-hora** cuando en la **base de datos** se espera **un tipo date**, por tanto prueba este código:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaAlta", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtmFechaAlta.Value.Date;
```

Es decir, solamente seleccionarías la parte de la fecha del componente **dateTimePicker** y seria esto lo que se guardaría en la base de datos.

También prueba esta otra forma:

```
DateTime miFecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaAlta", SqlDbType.Date).Value = miFecha;
```

De esta forma obtenemos la fecha del **dateTimePicker** con determinado formato **("dd-MM-yyyy")** y la guardamos en la **variable miFecha**, posteriormente el valor de esta variable es el que le damos al **parametro FechaAlta**.

Comment: Hola amigo, probé como me indicaste pero me aparece este error: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.'" como podre cambiarlo?

Comment: @lavasoftNelson, Revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: me funciono con este codigo
  ` cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaAlta", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtmFechaAlta.Value.Date; `

 que me pusiste, me anduvo de 10, muchas gracias genio!

Comment: @lavasoftNelson, que bueno que te funciono, podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Hola amigo, intento darle un voto a tu respuesta pero no me deja, como debo hacerlo? soy nuevo en este foro

Comment: @lavasoftNelson no te preocupes por eso, para poder emitir votos positivos debes tener 15 ptos de reputación y tu solo tienes 3, a medida que vayas interactuando más con la comunidad irás cogiendo más ptos